# Port 25 blocked, change ubuntu mailout to open port

Tags: email, ubuntu, postfix

My ISP blocked my port 25 (comcast), so I can't send mailout (via postfix).  Can I modify to send mail out on 587 or so?  I'm having issues figuring it out correctly.

Comment: It depends on your mail routing scheme. Please show how your postfix configured.

Comment: it's the default configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this link will help you: http://www.freebsddiary.org/postfix-transport.php

Comment: This is a great article, but it's extremly dated.  Anything for Ubuntu 10+ ?

Answer (score 3):

You *can* configure Postfix to send mail to port 587 of other servers. The problem is that they won't *accept* it. 587, the "Message submission" port, is strictly limited to *users* sending outgoing mail, and always requires authentication; for mail incoming from other servers, only port 25 is used.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use port 587 as the submission port for SMTP mail rather than 25 (many ISPs block port 25), you will need to edit /etc/postfix/master.cf to uncomment the relevant line for port 587 there.

Comment: I set up 587 in the masterc.cf; but for some reason it's still pushing on 25 (i commented out the smtp line for 25)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to relay mail through the Comcast mail server? If so, checkout [this article](http://www.justatheory.com/computers/mail/postfix-and-comcast.html).

Comment: If I relay through comcast, does the from come from the comcast acct email?  I've got a very large email qty to shoot out to my subscribers.

Comment: @Michael I don't know for sure. You can easily test this.